# Query between 2 date fields to retrive all datas less than 2 weeks

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table where i keep track of Posts replies,

```
USERID POSTEDTDATE             REPLYDDATE
------ ----------------------- -----------------------
26167  2012-03-12 00:00:00.000 2012-03-19 00:00:00.000 
26362  2012-03-17 00:00:00.000 2012-04-02 00:00:00.000 
26411  2012-04-10 00:00:00.000 2012-05-01 00:00:00.000 
26491  2012-04-09 00:00:00.000 2012-04-12 00:00:00.000
```

i want to get the count result for the replies for less than 15 day!?

```
SELECT COUNT(sms_Mailing.nameSurname)
FROM sms_Mailing
WHERE sms_Mailing.replyDate <= '".date('Y-m-j' ,strtotime('+2 weeks' , strtotime (sms_Mailing.replyDate)))."'
```

tried something like this but seems to be not a good soultion
can someone help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the date like that:

```
DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

or

```
DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

And then the query could be:

```
SELECT COUNT(sms_Mailing.nameSurname)
FROM sms_Mailing
WHERE sms_Mailing.replyDate > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) you can see other `INTERVAL` options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
where replyDate <= DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```